How can I improve the focus of my question about a reservation time overlap problem with MongoDB?
I'm working on booking service and I use MongoDB as the primary database.
I encountered a problem with race conditions while working on reservation time overlap validations with MongoDB. So I asked a question here, but my question has been closed as not focused. But to me it looks like my question is as focused as it could be, I don't see how it could be more focused. I think that I described the problem with all necessary details. Could someone explain how I can make my question more focused?
I tried to:

edit the title to fit better
add section "to be precise"

but nothing helps.

I'd rather have closed as needs debugging details. No queries, no code, no model structure, no nothing. You are expecting people to essentially open a portal to your machine so they can look there to know what's going on.

I don't know anything about your question topic, but I appreciate your respectful disagreement with the closure of your question. Too many come here to rage at the site instead of to discuss their disagreement.

When you posted this on the main site, did you read the tag description which clearly tells you "NOT THIS WEBSITE! Use this tag for the error caused by pushing too many items onto the callstack. If you have a question regarding this website, please go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com" ?

The problem is very often that people decide about questions that are not very familiar with the topic in question. To me it is completely clear what your issue is, however, I fear, that you do not have a good option for this in mongodb; this is a good fit for ACID transactions that you do not have available in your DBMS of choice here. You cannot use upsert here because the predicate of your existence check is too complex. For most relational databases this would be no problem.

That is a good point, I would have skipped myself because I don't know enough about MongoDB :) But what I said is then the wrong decision I would have found more logical given the circumstances. It's no longer about what is intended, it is about what you can show. A question of that magnitude without any kind of spec or code in it... destined to fail.

Identify the problem and make sure the question is only about that
You say in your question that "At some point I encountered a problem with race conditions".
First off, did you verify this? How?
Then - why does the question title say something about a "reservation time overlap"? This doesn't agree with the problem description. The title makes it sound like you're having a problem with the logic to figure out a "free" block of time in the schedule, but in the question you suggest that the problem is with two separate runs of the code seeing the same open time block and both trying to reserve it. This terminology is also unclear to begin with - because it's talking about the task that you're trying to complete (which nobody has any idea about until they read the question). In your title, you should talk about the problem in terms of the problem. If you think there's a race condition, then say so in the title.
Then, you say:

So my question is how to handle race-conditions in cases with complicated validation before insert with MongoDB (in particular in my case)?

First off - if you have a how-to question, then you should not present a "please fix my code" question. (And if you have a "please fix my code" question, then you need to show a proper Minimal Reproducible Example - "My code roughly:" is simply not useful to anyone.)
Second - do you believe that "complicated validation" means that standard solutions for "how to handle race conditions" won't work? If so, why? Did you try something? What did you try? What happened when you tried it, and how does that imply that the validation is interfering with the solution?
One of the answers in the other question you found (which also needs more focus, honestly) indicates that you should use a transaction, so that you get atomic behaviour - that is: make sure that the validation is performed and the booking updated, all at once for a given process, before any other process is allowed to check the same model. I can't see a reason here why "complex validation" would cause a problem for the approach. If you discovered such a reason, you need to explain it. Saying "in my case I don't have booking for day as a whole, but instead I have booking for "continuous" pieces of time" doesn't help, because you haven't given a reason why this should matter.
Doing the expected work makes it easier to look for a duplicate
And now you also see why we want question titles to talk about the problem - so that you can look for an existing question that's about the problem, rather than about the task. You should never expect anyone else to have your exact task. If they did, why would you bother to write a program, instead of just using theirs?
If I put is:question [mongodb] race condition into the site search I get a couple hundred results. It seems like what you're looking for is really Preventing database-related race conditions in Node.js . The point is: the specific details of your booking algorithm are not considered relevant to the race condition, until you prove that they are. If you think the problem is "2 persons try to book the same time simultaneously", then it probably doesn't matter what steps are involved in "book a time". Address the "simultaneously" problem first, and see what happens.

"First off, did you verify this? How?" it's a fairly trivial one. If you have two processes that do a read followed by a write, then the two reads and two writes can execute in basically any order. It's one of the most fundamental things to deal with in databases. A scenario like read1 -> read2 -> write1 -> write2 (when both operate on the same data) is one of almost an intrinsic property of using a database with any sort of multi-user (or multiple processes) environment. I personally don't think the question needs any more details. The flaw there is indeed obvious.

@Ctx No, there really are many things wrong with the question. Asking a proper question is hard, by design, because the purpose is not to get your problem solved, but to help build the site. We've been over this many times. I have no idea what you mean by "the site they appreciate most". The goal of Stack Overflow is explicitly laid out in many places.

@VLAZ I'm not asking for details, but for clarity via being explicit. Of course OP verified it, and of course there's only one real way to verify it. The question should still describe such a verification process, because that makes the question easier to understand - not for people who will answer, but for future searchers. I'm also asking for the removal of irrelevant details, on the same principle.
